# How to force multithread on video rendering?

Tags: rendering, video

I use Blender as a video montage software and the issue happens during rendering.

Blender doesn't use all the cores of the machine. In fact it uses only one. However, I set the *threads* value to fixed 8.

[image]

And I still have a single thread rendering.

[image]

I thought I could find the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62930/multiple-blender-threads-targetting-cpu-and-gpu) but obviously it's not the same problem.

The GPU is unemployed too.

Who knows how to use the whole machine?

Edit: I precise that I use Linux and other softwares work fine with multithreading.

Comment: As far as I know, the video sequence editor (sequencer) is singlethreaded. There are already multiple unanswered question with similiar problems.

Comment: Blender Video Sequence Editor uses FFMPeg as an external encoder, as far as I know, and it may not support passing threading parameteres through, not sure.

Comment: Ok, if it's ffmpeg-dependant, it seems that  ffmpeg should be compiled with multithreading options. I'll explore this and come back to you...

Comment: Possible some encoding libraries in FFMPEG don't support threaded encoding. What format and container are you exporting to?

Comment: QuickTime/h264 or avi/h264. The avi/h264 supports the multithread in mencoder, already tested...

Answer (score 6):

You can use Pulverize to do multi-process rendering from Blender's Video Sequence Editor:

https://github.com/sciactive/pulverize

Pulverize will render multiple parts of your video in separate processes, then concatenate them into one video file using FFMPEG. It uses the Blender command line to select frame ranges for each render.

Comment: Indeed. I wrote this because I had checked all these threads looking for an answer, but didn't find any. This is a solution for all of these duplicate questions on here.

Comment: @HunterPerrin Thanks for digging around and answering all these. However, in the future please flag/vote to close duplicate questions rather than duplicating answers.