# Can your CPU and GPU render different scenes at the same time?

Tags: rendering, gpu, scene

Can your CPU and GPU render different scenes at the same time?
Ex. Can a CPU(3900x) render an image of a car, while your GPU(3070) renders a house in a separate blender scene?
Well it probably can if you have 2 windows open, but will it be much slower than if you waited and rendered each scene one after another?

Comment: Can you? Yes. Shoud you? Probably not. Sounds like you already answered your own question. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62930

Comment: Keep in mind that GPU rendering does not mean that the CPU is idle. Not all operations are carried out by the GPU.